# Изменение цвета при нажатии кнопки

Tags: android

Подскажите, как в Android изменить цвет кнопки при нажатии на неё. Цвет должен изменяться "по кругу", цветов должно быть больше двух.

Comment: похоже на тестовое задание, добавьте ваши текущие наработки, покажите где у вас возникли конкретные трудности.

Comment: не тестовое, нашёл в самоучителе по андроид. Трудность в том как сделать именно это изменение.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842447/android-set-button-background-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея следующая, вы создаёте массив цветов и его индекс. По нажатию изменяете индекс на следующий и вытаскиваете цвет из массива цветов.

```
private int currentColor = 0;

private int[] colors = {0xFFFF0000, 0xFF00FF00, 0xFF0000FF}; 

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
     currentColor = (currentColor+1) % colors.length;
     ((Button) v).setBackgroundColor(colors[currentColor]);
  }
});
```